# What does the title attribute do in HTML links

Tags: html

I'm currently working with links as I'm learning HTML, and I wanted to know what the title attribute did.

```
<a href="intro.htm" title="Introduction to HTML">Introduction to HTML</a>
```

So, what does `title="Introduction to HTML"` do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute it's a tooltip and if the link text is something like "click here", then you might put something more meaningful in the `title` attribute for screen readers, bots, etc. There are other uses in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title attribute will help you display a message to the User, when hover over it.

Run the following example to understand better -

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="google.com" title="Click to go to google page">
            Hover to understand
        </a>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp) the title attribute specifies extra information about an element often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.

It is good for SEO, always a good idea to provide your keywords on titles for the Google spider to index your content.

Also it's a must when it comes to images for accessibility purposes.

Comment: "It is good for SEO" - is there any confirmation/research of that, or is it just a popular saying repeated without checking?

Comment: The different bits of information in this answer are respectively not correct and not relevant.